# Time Complexity of operation - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

I was wonder what the time complexity of certain operation in python are:

```
x = k * l ( multiplication )

x = k/l ( division )

math.sqrt(y)

math.pow(y,f)
```

and what is the complexity for using a while - loop.

Answer (score 4):

I truly believe it's the same in Python as in every other common languages?

```
x = k * l # multiplication  -> O(n²)

x = k/l # division -> O(n²)

math.sqrt(y) # -> O(M(n))

math.pow(y,f) # -> O(M(n))k), n digits number and k bit exponent 

while loop # -> O(n) ,same as For loop.
```

Edit : For multiplication, Python uses the [standard multiplication algorithm](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b514339e41ef/Objects/longobject.c#l2570) O(n²) but for very big numbers, it goes with [Karatsuba algorithm](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b514339e41ef/Objects/longobject.c#l2694), so O(n^1.585) according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm).