# What's the time complexity for the following python function?

Tags: python, time-complexity

```
def func(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return func(n-1) + n*(n-1)

print func(5)
```

Getting confused. Not sure what exactly it is. Is it `O(n)`?

Comment: Yes, it is `O(n)`.

Comment: @DAle why is it O(n)?

Answer (score 5):

Calculating the `n*(n-1)` is a fixed time operation. The interesting part of the function is calling `func(n-1)` until `n` is `1`. The function will make `n` such calls, so it's complexity is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that arithmetic operations are constant time operations (and they really are when numbers are relatively small) then time complexity is `O(n)`:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + C = T(n-2) + C + C = ... = n * C = O(n)
```

But the multiplication complexity in practice depends on the underlying type (and we are talking about Python where the type depends on the value). It depends on the `N` as `N` approaches infinity. Thus, strictly speaking, the complexity is equal to:

```
T(n) = O(n * multComplexity(n))
```

And this `multComplexity(n)` depends on a specific algorithm that is used for multiplication of huge numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As described in other answers, the answer is close to `O(n)` for practical purposes. For a more precise analysis, if you don't want to make the approximation that multiplication is constant-time:

Calculating `n*(n-1)` takes `O(log n * log n)` (or `O(log n)^1.58`, depending on the algorithm Python uses, which depends on the size of the integer). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020182/time-complexity-of-operation-python) - note that we need to take the `log` because the complexity is relative to the number of digits.

Adding the two terms takes `O(log n)`, so we can ignore that.

The multiplication gets done `O(n)` times, so the total is `O(n * log n * log n)`. (It might be possible to get this bound tighter, but it's certainly larger than `O(n)` - see the [WolframAlpha plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t(n)%20%3D%20t(n-1)%20%2B%20(log%20n)**2)).

In practice, the `log` terms won't really matter unless `n` gets very large.

Comment: Addition and Multiplication is in general seen as an O(1) operation. So the recursion defines the complexity, i.e., func(n-1). Thus, as already answered in the comments and by @Mureinik the complexity is in O(n).

Comment: For finite values of `n`, e.g. 64-bit values, the time complexity can be thought of as O(1); for arbitrary large values of `n` (when O-notation becomes "meaningful"), there are better-than-quadratic algorithms for multiplication - e.g. Karatsuba - (log n)^1.58

Comment: @meowgoesthedog sure, so replace ```log n * log n``` with ```(log n)^1.58```. My point is that it's not technically ```O(n)```; as I wrote in the last line, it's going to be close enough in most cases.

Comment: This looks like a classical homework assignment to me. If we want technically true we would have to know the data type otherwise every answer can be argued against. For example the n == 1 could take exponential time in some cases, if we would like to use exact arithmetic for example.

Comment: I see your point, yes. `n` may not necessarily be a native integer type, but some arbitrary precision class which has overloaded operators. If this were a strongly typed language (e.g. C) then we would have a definitive answer