# Findning time complexity O(n)

Tags: python, time-complexity

Consider this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Returns 2^n
def pow(n):

    if n == 0:
        return 1
    x = pow(n//2)
    if n%2 == 0:
        return x*x
    return 2*x*x

y = [10^4, 10^5,10^6, 10^7, 10^8, 10^9, 10^10]
z = []

for n in y:

    start = time.time()
    pow(n)
    print(n, time.time() - start) # elapsed time
    z.append(time.time()-start)

plt.plot(y,z)
plt.show()
```

I am trying to figure out what's the time complexity of the recursive
function `pow(n)`.

I calculated the time complexity as `O(log(n))` but when using the function
`time.time()` the function appears to be linear. How come?

Why is the time complexity `O(n)` and not `O(log(n))`?

[image: Graph]

Comment: How do you know that your results indicate that the time complexity is O(N)? If you're drawing that conclusion because the plot looks like a flat line, keep in mind that a logarithm curve _also_ looks flat if you zoom in on it far enough.

Comment: Your Y values increase exponentially, but your Y axis scale is linear, which means 90% of the graph consists of a single line from Y = 10^9 to Y = 10^10 – not enough to deduce the curve type.

Comment: Just added a graph, increasing the n with a factor 10 also increases the time taken by a factor 10.

Comment: 10^4=14 ;) Should be 1e4..

Comment: @user1587520 yes, in my code it says 10**4 and so on, but had a problem with the format. So I changed it here, sorry im inexperienced with stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace all appearances of `x*x` in your example with a constant (e.g. `1`) or multiplication with addition, you will see that you indeed get `O(log(n))` complexity, as your function is invoked `log(n)` times (though we measure really small times in this case, so the results of using `time` might not reflect the complexity of the function in this case). I think the conclusion is that your assumption that multiplication is `O(1)` is not correct (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020182/time-complexity-of-operation-python)), in particular as the numbers you multiply are really large and don't fit anymore in a traditional 32/64-bit representation.